# What color is that? Building a color theme for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When customizing my Visual Studio color scheme I am often confounded by the "Fonts and Colors" area.

[image: vs colors]

Often, I want to change a specific color, say: the color used for `TODO` lines, but I need to read through 100s of color names just to figure out what that is. Often I am unable to figure what what color is what.

Is there any documentation out there that lists which colors are which?

Or even better, is there a plugin that allow me to highlight text in the editor and change the scheme of the selected text (figure out what color/s it is)?

Comment: Unfortunately, not that I know.  This is _sorely_ needed.

Comment: Your picture made me lol and think of gawker.

Comment: Hmmm, is that data stored in XML?  Seems like it should trivial enough to create an app that loads the XML and lets you adjust the colors in a GUI or something...  Surely its more difficult than this otherwise someone would have done it already?

Comment: 2014 and the [VS Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378) is an awesome tool that addresses some of this, but I'm still guessing at the actual color names :( We still need an interactive selector to have a fighting chance. I even resorted to default themes for a while.

Answer (score 9):

I totally agree that this list is messy.

I personally find the [Studio Styles](http://studiostyl.es/) page helpful to create Visual Studio color schemes.

If you click on [Create a scheme](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/create) and hover over the different code elements it will show you a tooltip with the naming of that item to find it in Visual Studio (like `Keyword`, `User Types(Delegates)`, `Brace Matching(Rectangle)` etc.):

[image]

Of course you could also just build the complete theme then on their page and export it. It also provides an import functionality to change your pre-existing Visual Studio scheme directly there.

Anyhow, I would also love to have an extension to do so directly in Visual Studio ;)

Comment: This is a good method, but the Studio Styles page doesn't appear to be updated for Visual Studio 2015, which added different display items for Fonts and Colors. Also, hovering over the JS code shows "Script Identifier", but there is no display item called that.

Comment: It's actually just called "Identifier". (This is the one I was looking for.) I wish I had a list of what color defaults changed between versions...

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.

I think the answer is no.

Point it out at the [place where they monitor](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Comment: submitted to connect here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/648199/what-color-is-that-building-a-color-theme-for-visual-studio

Comment: Probably because someone thought it didn't qualify as an answer. It might be better suited as a comment.

Comment: @Sam I see the case was closed at April 1st last year - did you find anything else since?