# How can I make older color schemes compatible with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2015

In VS 2013, I use the [Selenitic color scheme](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/selenitic). When importing it in VS 2015, I see some differences.

VS 2013:
[image: screenshot of Visual Studio 2013]

VS 2015:
[image: screenshot of Visual Studio 2015]

There are some differences (interface color, XML comment color), the thing that annoys me the most is that the XML comments in 2013 are nicely colored and in 2015 it is all the same color. I also noticed that xml comments are using a different color. I like the syntax highlighting in 2013, the XML comments are more subtle there. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Perhaps this is just a bug for the custom theme. At the link you posted only compat with VS 2010 - 2013 is claimed at the moment. Maybe submit it as an issue there (too)?

Comment: Which setting is it so i can manually edit the theme, i can't find the name for the correct setting to edit.

Comment: Tools => Options, then under Environment => Fonts and Colors.  You can edit all of the editor colors there.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis That's where you edit them but what if you use something like http://studiostyl.es to edit every color in the text editor? 2015 can't import color settings from 2013. That's insane IMO

Comment: @Brandon Visual Studio 2015 can definitely import color settings exported from Visual Studio 2013.  I've been using the same color settings since Visual Studio 2012 and have never had any trouble importing them.

Comment: It refuses to work for me. I am trying to do it manually but it's a nightmare

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Your statement isn't 100% accurate. While it is true that importing works, many color settings have changed locations. As such, themes from before 2015 may not look entirely the same.

Comment: @JustinSkiles Perhaps that is the case for some languages; I only use C++, which hasn't changed much since Visual Studio 2012 when semantic colorization was added to the IDE.

Comment: For me importing a VS2013 theme works, but the colors look weird (get swapped etc.) after restarting VS.

Comment: Have you tried: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b

Comment: I'm new to .Net and VS. I am using VS 2015 Community Edition and I am looking for a safe and reversible way to change syntax highlighting schemes. I tried visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com extension, but it has very few schemes (which are more related to the interface than the code itself). I see that OP tried using a studiostyl.es theme in VS 2015, but at studiostyl.es every theme is marked as compatible with VS 2008-2013, and not VS 2015. Is it generally safe to use such themes in VS 2015? Or should I assume that doing so will lead to similar problems that OP is reporting? Alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that some names of the elements in a .vssetting file have been changed. So, you need to rename them to the new ones to import it correctly. Here's the list of changed names which I found so far.

```
Old Name                                     ->  New Name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brace Matching (Rectangle)                   ->  brace matching
String(C# @ Verbatim)                        ->  string - verbatim
User Types                                   ->  class name
User Types(Enums)                            ->  enum name
User Types(Interfaces)                       ->  interface name
User Types(Delegates)                        ->  delegate name
User Types(Value types)                      ->  struct name
Line Numbers                                 ->  Line Number
Razor Code                                   ->  RazorCode
XML Doc Comment                              ->  xml doc comment - text
XML Doc Tag                                  ->  xml doc comment - delimiter
                                                 xml doc comment - name
MarkerFormatDefinition/HighlightedReference  ->  MarkerFormatDefinition/HighlightedReference
                                                 MarkerFormatDefinition/HighlightedDefinition
```

I believe this is not all, but at least it includes the missing colors you showed.

Comment: That's perfect - I just got a 2013 theme from one of the usual places (studiostyl.es/) and edited the file in a text editor replacing everything as you'd specified. All looks perfect!

Comment: LinqPad script to do these replacements: https://gist.github.com/JohannesRudolph/52073f4ac6dc893d9548

Comment: @JohannesRudolph the last two are not simply replacements, they're split up in multiple settings.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't specifically fix the import of a scheme, but the XML comment colors (in VS2015) can be manually changed

Assuming the following comment block

```
/// <summary>
/// Description
/// </summary>
/// <param name="test">Value</test>
/// <returns>Result</returns>
```

Go to Tools / Environment / Fonts and Colors:

There are a section of options all starting with "XML Doc Comments - ". Change each of these to change the corresponding part of the comment.

```
Delimiter:        /// < < /

Name:             summary, param, returns

Attribute Quotes: "

Attribute Name:   name

Text:             Description, Value, Result
```

I cannot find an option to independently color "test" above - it appears to be linked with "Identifier".

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty annoyed with the color changes. So far, I've found that Visual Studio 2015 has these differences:

- Added new items (Display items) in the list
- Split a single item into multiple items, some with a different color than before

  1. User Types. Enums, Interfaces, and Type Parameters have a more pale green. Old color: `rgb(78,201,176)`
- Changed default colors for some items

  1. All comments were made a brighter green. Old color: `rgb(96,139,78)`

     - (Note that there are 8 different items relating to comments: Comment, CSS Comment, HTML Comment, VB XML Literals - Comment, VBScript Comment, XAML Comment, XML Comment, and XML Doc Comments - Comment.)
  2. Identifiers (e.g. JavaScript code) made dimmer. Old color: `white`
  3. HTML Entities changed to some blue-ish color. Old color: `silver`
  4. more...

Note that the colors listed are defaults for the "Dark" theme, with the "old colors" being listed from Visual Studio 2012. The differences above are the most noticeable differences that I saw, since I wanted to change the JS color and the comment colors. There are probably others I haven't noticed yet.

If you need more help, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145087/2415524) was also somewhat helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: avoid VS all together for theme management.

I agree with @Brandon on this. Backward incompatibility for font settings is insane for Microsoft and, unfortunately, a poor first impression for many of us when we upgrade to a new VS version. Just don't use VS for theme management (yes, it should just work, but after all Microsoft is focused on delivering more innovative features than making our IDE's look pretty).

Luke Sampson at Studio Styles (https://studiostyl.es/) does an amazing job keeping look & feel consistent while dealing with all the annoying label changes and other mappings that beak cross version setting export/import. Takes some time for the initial set up but after that you can export the version you need. Best part, it works...